# Android ListView elements bumping

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView that each row has a title on the left side and then a date and some metadata on the right.

The titles are created by the user and can be of arbitrary length.

I am finding that if the title is too long, it is bumping into the date.

How can I limit the title display size, making it larger or smaller depending on the screen resolution, so that it doesn't bump into the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a relative layout, and put your textview relatively to your date. Also use android:ellipsize="marquee" for your textview so that text will be cut if needed.